# How to read the JSON String

Tags: json

Kindly need your help as this really taking me long time to try. From JSP, I passed the stingnify JSON object as a String to the Java action, it like

String jsonDealer = [{"dealerID":"VARSSWK103","dealerName":"Dealer ABC"}, 
{"dealerID":"VARSSTH008","dealerName":"Dealer XYZ"}]

How I can convert this to JSON object/ or ArrayList of Dealer, so that I can retrieve the dealer ID and dealer name?

Thanks for all help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, download [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Second, create this class:

```
class Dealer {
    Dealer() {}
    public void setDealerID(String dealerID) {
        this.dealerID = dealerID;
    }
    public String getDealerID() {
        return dealerID;
    }
    public void setDealerName(String dealerName) {
        this.dealerName = dealerName;
    }
    public String getDealerName() {
        return dealerName;
    }
    private String dealerID;
    private String dealerName;


}
```

Third, use this code:

```
String jsonDealer = "[{\"dealerID\":\"VARSSWK103\",\"dealerName\":\"Dealer ABC\"}, {\"dealerID\":\"VARSSTH008\",\"dealerName\":\"Dealer XYZ\"}]";

Gson gson = new Gson();

Type type = new TypeToken<List<Dealer>>(){}.getType();

List<Dealer> fromJson = gson.fromJson(jsonDealer, type);

System.out.println(fromJson.get(0).getDealerName());   // example usage
```

Comment: +1, although there are, of course, lots of other options. Google GJSON isn't the only game in town...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: of course, but since I have only GSON set up, why not give a concrete example?

Comment: Sure, and that's why I voted it up. It's just that the answer doesn't give any indication that one has options. I'm a big fan of options.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a JSON deserializer. There are quite a few for Java listed at the bottom of [the JSON.org page](http://json.org). As of this writing:

- [org.json.](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)
- [org.json.me.](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/)
- [Jackson JSON Processor.](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
- [Json-lib.](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)
- [JSON Tools.](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/jsontools/)
- [json-simple.](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)
- [Stringtree.](http://www.stringtree.org/stringtree-json.html)
- [SOJO.](http://sojo.sourceforge.net/)
- [Restlet.](http://www.restlet.org/)
- [google-gson.](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

...and 10 more. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a json parsing api like [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the json string. Follow the simple tutorial in my website http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/json_to_java.php

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a JSON library for Java which can parse the string into an object / collection.

I'm not a Java expert myselft, but this list might have somethng suitable: http://www.json.org/java/